# Get Quotes for stock prices in GnuCash using Finance::Quote

Tags: command-line, perl, finance

I have followed the instructions [here](http://www.askmeaboutlinux.com/?p=1709), using the exact example, to have automatic stock price updates in GnuCash. When I click `price editor -> Get Quotes` it returns in a warning `Unable to retrieve quotes for these items: NS:HDIL.NS` (also there is another one I tried too).

I installed `gnc-fq-update` following the instructions on the GnuCash mailing list [here](http://gnucash.1415818.n4.nabble.com/Installing-activeperl-for-automatic-retrieval-of-quotes-td4656798.html#a4656799). And when I type into the terminal `cpan -D Finance::Quote` as instructed to do so in the GnuCash wiki for CPAN the terminal returns

```
Going to read '/home/anthony/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 14 May 2014 02:06:11 GMT
Finance::Quote
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (no description)
    E/EC/ECOCODE/Finance-Quote-1.31.tar.gz
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Finance/Quote.pm
    Installed: 1.31
    CPAN:      1.31  up to date
    Erik Colson (ECOCODE)
    eco@ecocode.net
```

Comment: I realise this is not directly related to Ubuntu, although I am using Ubuntu. I would be glad if someone could suggest a more appropriate stackexchange forum to use.

Comment: If you get nothing here, you could ask on the GnuCash mailing list?

Comment: Thank you I followed this advice and resolved the problem through the GNUcash mailing list. I have explained my solution on superuser.stackexchange where my question (the same as above) was migrated from money.stackexchange.com. I add a link as the answer below.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out! I'd probably just delete this one, since it doesn't really add anything to the other. However, I'm not 100% sure what the policy is on cross-stack-exchange dupes, and you get 15 rep from this question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNUcash mailing list helped me to resolve this issue. My answer to the same question can be found on [superuser.stackexchange here](https://superuser.com/a/756467/325123)

(Perhaps these questions should be merged.)